# How to save PowerPoint 365 slide as image at Clipboard quality of JPG or PNG format ? Tech Support typically only supports JPG or PNG for upload

Tags: clipboard, jpeg, png

How to save slide as image at Clipboard quality?

```
1. Screen Capture quality visually identical to Monitor view
    1. sample of Screen Capture directly pasted
```

[image: sample of Screen Capture directly pasted]

```
2. file direct save nor export result in same quality as Screen Capture
    1. BMP
    2. TIF
    3. PNG
    4. sample of File Export as PNG format
```

[image: sample of File Export as PNG format]

```
3. Snip and Sketch is 
    1. more lossy than Screen Capture but 
    2. better than File Direct Save or Export but it can only approximate size of slide
    3. why is JPG less lossy than PNG or TIF or BMP format of File Direct Save or Export?
    4. sample of Snip and Sketch saved as JPG Format.
```

[image: sample of Snip and Sketch saved as JPG Format]

Reasons of asking

```
1. saving slide is I do not know how to exactly control size of screen capture.
```

JPG or PNG format are availabe for upload to Tech Support

Comment: What do you expect when you zoom into an image?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer which is to enlarge the slide size. Pls find below related VBA script
Here it is for others if interested. For me, VBA is to be avoided

> Answer AnswerUnmark as Answer
> Steve Rindsberg
> Steve Rindsberg
> MVP | Volunteer Moderator
> Replied on August 15, 2022
> This page from the PPTFAQ describes several ways of improving PowerPoint's File | Save As resolution:

https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00052_Improve_PowerPoint-s_GIF-_BMP-_PNG-_JPG_export_resolution.htm

PowerPoint Help:
https://www.pptfaq.com/
PPTools:
https://www.pptools.com
Reply